# Simplicial matrices and the nerves of weak n-categories II, III, and IV

Tags: reference-request, higher-category-theory, simplicial-stuff, 2-categories

Duskin introduced his nerve functor (see the [nLab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/geometric+nerve+of+a+bicategory) or [Kerodon](https://kerodon.net/tag/009P)) in the paper

> **Duskin**, John W. Simplicial matrices and the nerves of weak n-categories I: nerves of bicategories. [[Link]](http://www.tac.mta.ca/tac/volumes/9/n10/9-10abs.html).

While three other sequel papers were announced as "to appear", they never did. On the other hand, some papers (e.g. [[1]](https://arxiv.org/abs/1907.01999), [[2]](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.agt/1513715161)) cite drafts/preprints of the second part of Duskin's work. Is it available somewhere?

Comment: Well, an obligatory question: have you tried emailing Duskin himself?

Comment: @DmitriPavlov Not yet; I thought asking here first might be a good idea. (Would it be better in this kind of situation to try emailing the author before asking here?)

Comment: Considering that these papers were announced a long time ago and nothing like these papers appears in the list of papers actually published by Duskin, the most likely answer is that these papers were never written.  And Duskin is much more likely to give a definitive answer in this case than anybody on MathOverflow.

Comment: I'll email Duskin soon then. Thanks, @Dmitri!